# Should the X-UA-Compatible meta tag come before or after the charset tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

I need to force IE9 to use its standards mode, and have the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Is it correct to have the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag appear before the `X-UA-Compatible` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `X-UA-Compatible` header isn't case sensitive; however, it must appear in the header of the webpage (the HEAD section) *before all other elements except for the title element and other meta elements*.

Source: [*Specifying Legacy Document Modes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: So, does this means that we can set it before or after the utf-8 meta tag?